# How to Change my free app with in-app purchase to paid app android?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-billing

Already I am having a free Android app with the in-app purchase in Google play store. Now as per our requirement I want to change it to a paid app. But somewhere I found that a free Android app with in-app purchase cannot be changed to paid app whereas a paid app can be changed to a free app. Is this possible now?

If we have to do it how can we do it? Do I have to create a new App with the different package name or am I just change something in the existing package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way you can change a free app to a paid app. Whenever you select the type of application from Play Console, in Pricing and Distribution, they give you a clear warning,

> An app that was published as 'Free' cannot be changed to 'Paid'.

If you want to change the app to paid, you need to create a new app with new package name and set the price.

[More info can be found here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?visit_id=636952357639687424-4283858098&rd=1#paid_free)

Answer (score 3):

*Extract from guidelines:*

**Changes to your app's Free or Paid selection**

- You can change your app from Paid to Free.
- Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price.